# Multithreading not running on parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, javafx-8, fxml

I started learning Java programming 3 days ago, before I was only able to code PHP etc. Now I have met a problem - I tried to make a server-client chat with multiple clients, where client's data is stored in an array when connecting(socket, datainputstream and dataoutputstream). Anyway, everything compiles like it should, but I have used 2 threads with runnable interface, but these threads are not running in parallel. First I started the server, then I started first client. The first client says it's connected to the server, but server doesn't recognise it. When starting second client, server recognises it and saves the data in the arrays, but when trying to write a text from client using writeUTF(), the server's MessageTransport thread doesn't work. Here is the full code, I'm using javafx with fxmlloader:
Chat Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ClientHandler extends Server implements Runnable{

    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    ClientHandler(String name){
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Creating thread: " + name);
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Running thread: " + threadName);
        /*try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
        while(true){
            try{
                Socket s;
                if((s = ss.accept()) != null){
                    clientSockets.add(s);
                    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    dinStreams.add(din);
                    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    doutStreams.add(dout);

                    System.out.println("Client connected. Added to list.");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Starting thread: " + threadName);
        if(t == null){
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Failed to start thread " + threadName + ". Thread already started.");
        }
    }
}

class MessageTransport extends Server implements Runnable{

    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    MessageTransport(String name){
        threadName = name;
        System.out.println("Creating thread: " + name);
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Running thread: " + threadName);
        /*try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        System.out.println("Ready to transport messages...");
        while(true){
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<clientSockets.size();i++){
                try{
                    DataInputStream din = dinStreams.get(i);
                    if(!din.readUTF().equals("")){
                        int v;
                        for(v=0; v<clientSockets.size(); v++){
                            DataOutputStream dout = doutStreams.get(v);
                            dout.writeUTF(din.readUTF());
                            dout.flush();
                        }
                    }else if(din.readUTF().equals("/System_exit")){
                        System.out.println("Client left.");
                        din.close();
                        clientSockets.remove(i);
                        dinStreams.remove(i);
                        doutStreams.remove(i);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Starting thread: " + threadName);
        if(t == null){
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Failed to start thread " + threadName + ". Thread already started.");
        }
    }
}

public class Server {

    public static ServerSocket ss;
    public static List<Socket> clientSockets;
    public static List<DataInputStream> dinStreams;
    public static List<DataOutputStream> doutStreams;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(5000);
            clientSockets = new ArrayList<>();
            dinStreams = new ArrayList<>();
            doutStreams = new ArrayList<>();

            System.out.println("Server opened. Waiting for clients");
            ClientHandler CH = new ClientHandler("Client_Handler");
            CH.start();
            MessageTransport mt = new MessageTransport("Message Transmitter");
            mt.start();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Chat client files...
Main class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main extends Application{

    private static Socket s = null;
    private static Controller controller;
    private static String username = "priitkaard";
    private static DataOutputStream dout = null;
    private static DataInputStream din = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("chat_client.fxml"));
        VBox layout = loader.load();
        controller = loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Chatbox");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout, 600, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            if(s != null){
                try{
                    if(dout != null){
                        dout.writeUTF("/System_exit");
                    }
                    s.close();
                }catch(Exception l){
                    l.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Platform.exit();
        });
        try{
            s = new Socket("localhost", 5000);
            controller.writeln("Connected to the server.");
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        }catch(ConnectException cE){
            controller.writeln("Couldn't connect to the server.");
        }
        MessageListener ml = new MessageListener();
        ml.start();
    }
    public static Socket getSocket(){
        return s;
    }
    public static DataInputStream getDin(){
        return din;
    }
    public static DataOutputStream getDout(){
        return dout;
    }
    public static Controller getChatController(){
        return controller;
    }
    public static String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
class MessageListener implements Runnable{
    private String threadName;
    private Thread t;
    MessageListener(){
        threadName = "messageListener";
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Main.getSocket() != null){
            try{
                DataInputStream din = Main.getDin();
                while(true){
                    if(!din.readUTF().equals("")){
                        Main.getChatController().writeln(din.readUTF());
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Main.getChatController().writeln("No connection.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void start(){
        if(t == null){
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;


public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextArea a;
    @FXML private TextField b;

    public void writeln(String message){
        a.setText(a.getText() + "\n" + message);
    }

    @FXML void sendText(){
        if(b.getText().equals("/System_exit")){
            Platform.exit();
        }else{
            try{
                DataOutputStream dout = Main.getDout();
                dout.writeUTF(Main.getUsername() + ": " + b.getText());
                b.setText("");
                dout.flush();
            }catch(Exception e){
                writeln("Failed to send message.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                b.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

chat_client.fxml file (GUI):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<VBox fx:controller="sample.Controller" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <children>
      <TextArea id="textArea" fx:id="a" editable="false" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="580.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </VBox.margin>
      </TextArea>
      <HBox prefHeight="50.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="b" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="520.0">
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <Region prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="13.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button fx:id="c" onAction="#sendText" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Send" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

... and ofcourse if there are some ways I could improve my code, I would like to learn from my mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accepting a client twice in the run method of your ClientHandler.

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
                if((s = ss.accept()) != null){
```

What happens is that ss.accept() waits for a client to connect. Its connects, and it continues to the if statement. Here again you call ss.accept(), so again the server waits untill a client connects. This second ss.accept() prevents the rest of your code from running.

Solution: Get rid of one of the two ss.accept() statements. Example:

```
if(s!=null){
```

Comment: Oh right... I wanted to define variable s as Socket, but accidentally accepted it right away. Wasted my whole day on this one. Great, this fixed the threading problem, but there's another problem, texts are not going through, I can't find the issue...

Comment: Found the issue, but can't figure out what's wrong with it. The issue is the for loop in the MessageListener thread. while(true) runs until a client connects and then it stops, with out even going the for loop through one time. Edit: sorry, it goes through only once

Comment: Nevermind, I checked in the if statement in !din.readUTF().equals(""), that broke the loop, because there was nothing to read, I had to use if(din.available()). But thank you for the first solution!